# Convert / Replace tab stops to comma

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have Word documents which require me to convert or replace tab stops to commas.

The text may look like this:

```
Hello........world (dot)
Hello------------World (dash)
Hello____World (line)
Hello          world (none)
```

Word provides 4 choices for tab stops leader: dot, dash, line and none.
I would like to replace only the first 3 leader types into comma.

The last one won't be changed like this:

```
Hello,world
Hello,World
Hello,World
Hello          world
```

Find and Replace Tabs function in Word doesn't work. So I tried to "copy and paste" from various sources into a simple macro to do this task:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Content.Paragraphs
        For Each aTab In para.TabStops
            If aTab.Leader = wdTabLeaderDots _
              Or aTab.Leader = wdTabLeaderDashes _
              Or aTab.Leader = wdTabLeaderLines Then
                TypeText = ","
                aTab.Clear
            End If
        Next aTab
    Next para
End Sub
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192806.aspx

Word says there is an error in the line: TypeText = ",".

---

Slai has a solution for this question. I copied the second code into a macro, modified a little bit to make it work:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    Dim p As Paragraph, t As TabStop
        
    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        For Each t In p.TabStops
            If t.Leader Then p.Range.Find.Execute "^t", , , , , , , , , ",", wdReplaceAll
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

If you need the macro to work only with paragraphs in your selection, replace ActiveDocument into Selection.

Comment: maybe Find and Replace Format http://www.officearticles.com/word/find_and_replace_styles_in_microsoft_word.htm

Comment: @Slai I have tried Find and Replace feature in Word but it doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find and Replace Format seems to work only if the Tab stop positions are known:

```
With ThisDocument.Range.Find
    For L = wdTabLeaderDots To wdTabLeaderLines
        .ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=36, Leader:=L
        .Execute "^t", , , , , , , , , ",", wdReplaceAll
    Next
End With
```

Alternative can be to check the tab stops of each paragraph ( BTW [`WdTabLeader` has 6 values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845050.aspx) ) :

```
Dim p As Paragraph, t As TabStop

For Each p In ThisDocument.Paragraphs
    For Each t In p.TabStops
        If t.Leader Then p.Range.Find.Execute "^t", , , , , , , , , ",", wdReplaceAll
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I have copied your code into a new macro, run it but it didn't work. I don't understand the meaning of the part "^t", , , , , , , , , "," in your code.
Could you please help me with a more detailed macro? I'm totally new to Word macro or VBA. I have just learned a little bit about VBA or programming for a few days (based on Google search only) to solve some problems of my documents. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @doquan0 sorry, forgot to reply. What do you mean by it didn't work .. nothing happens at all? You can try replacing `ThisDocument` with `ActiveDocument`. `"^t"` is the special character for Tab and `","` is the 10th parameter `ReplaceWith` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193977.aspx

Comment: The second code Dim p As Paragraph ... Next Next works perfectly. Thank you a lot. As you said, I need to replace ThisDocument to ActiveDocument in the code to make it work. My bounty has expired so I cannot give you 50 points of reputation. However, I have marked this as an accepted answer to show my appreciation to you.

Comment: I have a problem with paragraphs containing multiple tab leaders. For example:`hello         world.....hello----world___hello            world`. With the second code you given, all the tab leaders in the paragraphs will be changed to comma - the result that I don't expect. Could you please help me with the macro so that it doesn't change to tab leader (none) into comma? Thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`TypeText` is a method of the `Selection` object. Since you don't specify the object, `TypeText` fails in your code. Since you also don't use the `Selection` object you can't use `TypeText` at all. I suggest a structure like this one.

```
With Para.Range
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Move wdCharacter, -1
    .Text = ","
End With
```

This code would add a comma at the end of the paragraph, which brings you to the question where you want the comma to be. You want it in the place of the tab which is quite a different animal from the `TabStop`. A tab is a Chr(9) which you can replace easily enough. However, how this Chr(9) will be interpreted depends upon the type of `TabStop` set for it which would depend upon where on the page the Chr(9) takes effect. You can't tell that by examining the text. Therefore you can't differentiate between types of `TabStops` by looking at the document's text.

**To be clear:** It is not possible to replace a `TabStop` with a comma because a `TabStop` doesn't exist. It is possible to replace tabs with commas.

It is not possible to determine the leader of a particular tab without knowing its precise location in the text. Example: If a `TabStop` exists at 100pts from the left margin **and** a tab becomes effective in the space ending 100pts from the left margin, let's say 50pts, **and** there is no other `TabStop` set in the region between 50pts and 100pts from the left margin, **then** the tab in the document can be associated with the `TabStop` set at 100pts, its leader determined, and a replacement of the tab (not the `TabStop` !!!) enacted or omitted.

With knowledge of the precise location of the tab in the document it isn't possible to create an association between it and any of the tab stops in the paragraph. Since it isn't possible to determine which `TabStop` might become effective it is also impossible to make an educated guess as to any of its properties. Without precise knowledge of the tab's position in the document the only decision that can be made with its regard is whether to execute it or replace it - unconditionally.

Comment: I added your code after the line aTab.Clear. It adds a comma before the last character of the paragraph, like Hello(tab)Worl,d. I noticed that the line aTab.Clear in my code creates a normal tab. Would you be able to adjust the code so that that it adds a comma before or after the newly-created-normal tab, like Hello(tab),World?

Comment: A tab is a character like any other. You can search for it and replace it like any other. For that purpose one wouldn't use code like I posted above. It's just find and replace. Please differentiate clearly between tabs and tab stops. You can set as many tab stops in a paragraph as you wish, but none of them will ever become effective unless there is a tab in the text. Which tab stop is activated by a tab in the text depends upon where in a line the tab is placed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand the difference between tabs and tab stops. As you said, after I set a tab stop, I need to press 'Tab' button on my keyboard to activate it. The 'normal' tab I mean in my previous comment is that aTab.Clear deletes all tab stops and resets the format of all tabs. No dot, no dash and no line, even the space for all tabs is reset to Word's defaults (0.5 inch or 36 points).

Comment: I admit being confused now. A tab (= a character in the text) can be replaced with a comma. A tab stop (= an object of the paragraph format) can't be replaced with a comma. It is correct that Word will set default tab stops for stretches in a document's lines where the user didn't set any tab stops himself. Those stops are without leader and can't be deleted except by setting a tab stop at the end of the line.